# xcode-select --install not available on update server

Tags: macos, xcode, software-update

I'm trying to install the new command line tools in OS X 10.9, and I get this weird error from Apple.

> Can't install the software because it is currently available from the Software Update server.

`xcode-select --install`

[image: screenshot]

> A workaround is to download the tools from here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action –  nnyby

But that also returns an error.

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone offer an alternative way to download this?

Comment: A workaround is to download the tools from here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

Answer (score 6):

Xcode Command Line Tools can be downloaded directly from the Apple Developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-) as pointed out by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908327/645491).

You could also just run my [Xcode CLT install / bootstrap script](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/6217746/) if you're looking for a quick automated solution.

Comment: The search on that page seems to be kinda wonky, only showed old stuff for me. I recommend going to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and looking through the list manually, recent stuff is at the top, so if you're here because of a macOS beta, you'll find what you need at the top.

Comment: Yeah, they do change the CLT downloads often. Unfortunately Apple does not provide an easy programmatic way to get the latest download URLs. `developer.apple.com` using a browser seems to be the supported method.

Answer (score 1):

The site seems to be online again now. \o/

Here's a direct link to the download if the site goes offline again:

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013/command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013.dmg

Comment: It just produces 'Your session has expired'.

Comment: The link does not work anymore, but the answer by TrinitronX below works for everything before Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

This error could also mean that [you already have the command tools installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server#comment29960394_19907576). The error message should have been more on to the point.